# Context.Set<entity> saving data to related tables but it should only save in specific table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the method to save and get users.

```
 public Users UpdateUsers(Users user)
    {
        var userobj = Context.Set<Users>().Where(x => x.UserId == 
        user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is Interface of entity Context where Set<> method is defined

```
public interface IEntitiesContext
   {
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    void Dispose();
    int SaveChanges();
    DbChangeTracker ChangeTracker { get; }

    IList<TEntity> ExecuteStoredProcedureList<TEntity>(string commandText, 
    params object[] parameters) where TEntity : BaseEntity, new();

    Database Database { get; }
}
```

In Users there some properties of other tables and it is saving data to other table as well but it should save data to Users table only

Comment: How do you confirm that other table data also being saved? You need to make sure that that context is initialized only for specific operation and the disposed. If its shared between multiple operations then SaveChanges will save all the data which are changed in all the operations.

Comment: Can you share the repository code ?